# Ruby how to compare 2D arrays values

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

I have two question about array of arrays on Ruby :

first, i dont know how to compare this array of arrays

```
 a = [[1,2,3,5] , [1,2,3,6]]
```

(**Output**: 11 < 12 )

second , I want to merge them into one long array

```
   a = [[1,2,3] , [4,5,6]] 
=> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To get an item with max sum from array you can use this line:

```
a.max_by {|arr| arr.inject(0, &:+)}
```

And to get all uniq values from all arrays in parent array, use this line:

```
[[1,2,3] , [4,5,6]].flatten.uniq
```

Comment: In first line you can omit zero in parameters, using just `inject(&:+)` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your first question: Are you trying to compare the sums of the contents of your two arrays? If so you could do the following:

```
a = [[1,2,3,5],[1,2,3,6]]
a[0].inject(:+) < a[1].reduce(:+)
# returns true
```

Your second question: `a.flatten` will combine all of the elements into one array.

I'd recommend reading through the Ruby docs, as things like `inject` and `flatten` are explained in great detail.

Answer (score 0):

***first , i dont know how to compare this array of arrays a = [[1,2,3,5] , [1,2,3,6]] (try to get the answer 11 < 12 )***

You could do it by using

```
a = [[1,2,3,5] , [1,2,3,6]]
a[0].inject{|sum,x| sum + x } < a[1].inject{|sum,x| sum + x }
```

Or

```
a = [[1,2,3,5] , [1,2,3,6]]
a[0].reduce(:+) < a[1].reduce(:+)
```

You could also use `a[0].inject(:+) < a[1].inject(:+)`. Reduce emphasises [Map reduce verbage.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce)

***second , i want to merge them into one long array a = [[1,2,3] , [4,5,6]] => a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]***

```
a = [[1,2,3,5] , [1,2,3,6]]
concatenated = a.flatten
```

or

```
a = [[1,2,3,5] , [1,2,3,6]]
concatenated = a.reduce(:concat)
```

or

```
concatenated = a.reduce(:+)
```